# Tail probability of a max of iid

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X_{i}$ are iid random variables with $X_{i}>0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}>t)\sim t^{-\alpha}$ as $t\to \infty$.

Then my question is:  Is it also true that $\mathbb{P}(\max_{1,\dots n} X_{i}>t)\sim t^{-\alpha} $ or something similar of this form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $W$ be the maximum of the $X_i$, where $n$ is fixed.

Then $W\le t$ if and only if all the $X_i$ are $\le t$. This has probability $\sim(1-t^{-\alpha})^n$. Thus
$$\Pr(W\gt t)\sim 1-(1-t^{-\alpha})^n.$$
But for fixed $n$ and large $t$ we have, taking the first two terms of the binomial expansion,  $1-(1-t^{-\alpha})^n\sim nt^{-\alpha}$.